# manual or programmatic way of creating keyboard short-cuts for excel add-ins

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to have a shortcut like ctrl+p to run a certain macro? is there a manual or programmatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible manually. If you're recording the macro you can specify a hotkey before you start recording; otherwise you open the Macro dialog, select the macro from the list, and click the Options button